# Angular 7 and arrays pushing two arrays into one array is giving an error of undefined

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, angular7

I need to combine 2 arrays read from an excel file into 2-dimensional array, so I can place it as `dataSource` of material table.

I have these 2 arrays read from excel using `XLSX` library:

```
    reader.onload = (e) => {
      const res = reader.result as string; // This variable contains your file as text
      const lines = res.split('\n'); // Splits you file into lines
      let ids=[];
      let name = [];
      let array:any[][];
      lines.forEach((line, index) => {
        //console.log(line);
        ids.push((line.split(',')[0]));
        name.push(line.split(',')[1]);
        array.push([ids, name])
      });
      console.log(array);
    }
```

But I keep getting an error on `console.log(array)`:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

**EDIT**:

I changed the code into:

```
      let name = [];

      lines.forEach((line, index) => {
        //console.log(line);
        ids.push((line.split(',')[0]));
        name.push(line.split(',')[1]);
        array.push(ids, name)
      });
      console.log(array);
```

The result was like that:

[image]

But that's not what I need because it won't work as dataSource on material table.

Comment: Your array has no value bro. Says it right there.

Comment: I think you should assign empty array for your array like that :
`let array:any[]=[]`

Comment: @stwilz please check my edit at the end of the question

Comment: Just for the sake of correct tags - its a pure Javascript/Typescript issue. Not related to angular or xlsx

Comment: @everyBit please check my edit at the end of the question

Comment: @JonathanStellwag I have edited the tags. Didn't notice it until you mentioned thanks.

Comment: @alim1990 can you update your code above and show us what your expected result is?

Comment: what you mean by 2- dimensional array ?  each item should have name and id  ?

Comment: @programoholic I need to like id 0 is for a, 1 for b, 2 for c. In the image, you see that index 0 is just for IDs and index 1 is for names and so on.

Comment: @programoholic what I need is a fit-able array for material table datasource.

Comment: @alim1990 array of object wont fit for your requirement  ?

Comment: @and material table has two columns `id` and `name`  .. right  ?

Comment: yes @programoholic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your problem right...  here is the simple way to achieve your 
requirement.

```js
 let lines = ["1,xx","2,yy","3,zz"];
 let name = [];
 let array = [];
      lines.forEach((line, index) => {
        //console.log(line);
        let obj = { 
        id : line.split(',')[0],
        name : line.split(',')[1]
        };
        
        //ids.push((line.split(',')[0]));
        //name.push(line.split(',')[1]);
        array.push(obj)
      });
      
console.log(array);
```